# Rails Production FATAL: database "db/production.postgresql" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, capistrano

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma) from Digitalocean to set up my rails production server. However I am getting errors at `cap production deploy:initial`

My setup consist of Ubuntu 14.04,Capistrano,Nginx and Puma in Digitalocean.

In the tutorial, they did not mention about editing database.yml but I noticed I need to edit it as the default one was sqlite3 while my production db was postgresql.

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host      159.203.107.215: Exception while executing on host 159.203.107.215: rake     exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "db/production.postgresql" does not exist
```

**Database.yml**

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
pool: 5
timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
<<: *default
 database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
<<: *default
database: db/production.postgresql
```

Comment: Did you check this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-ubuntu-14-04 ?

Comment: yes I did set it up properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite and PostgreSQL require very different arguments to connect.  Sqlite just takes a path to the on disk database file. PostgreSQL needs connection info: hostname, db name, username, password.  I would get rid of your `default` stuff and make each one explicit.  Something like this:

```
development:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  encoding: unicode
  database: your_db_name_here
  host: your_db_host_here
  username: your_db_username_here
  password: your_db_password_here
```

I would also encourage you to not store the actual username and password in this file, but to grab it via the environment (dot_env gem can help as can several others).  Something like this:

```
username: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_USERNAME', '') %>
password: <%= ENV.fetch('DATABASE_PASSWORD', '') %>
```

Comment: I am getting Psych::BadAlias: Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Unknown alias: default.
.

Comment: That means you left a `<<: *default` in, but took out the `default:` block.